# Two nib file and one view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, nib

In my project i have created two `UIView` one for landscape mode and the other for potrait mode. I am using the same same `UIViewController` to control both these views. These two views have the same content, only thing is that when i switch from one `UIView` to another the value of the `UIControls` is not retained. 
I have loaded the UIView`enter code here` using the following code

```
NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UIViewName"
                                      owner:self
                                    options:nil];
        UIView *lview = (UIView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        lview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.jpg"]];
        self.view = lview;
```

Can anybody pliz help me retaining the values during orientation change?

Comment: all views are reset (so the user must re-enter text fields/views input). So, here with values i am actually referring to the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can stock all the values on a NSMutableDictionary in your controller and then put the inputs of the user on the reloaded views when the user changes the orientation.

Look here at theh documentation to see how NSMutableDictionary works:

[NSMutableDictionary Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsmutabledictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Can you provide the coding help

Comment: I'm sorry but that's your job not mine. Everything is on the internet I just gave you which way you should go. We are not here to code for you. We are here to help.

Comment: Thanks for not providing the code and letting us to do that. And also thanks for providing help.